# Arduino - Adding Characters from Serial to "Char" is not being printed favorably

Tags: c++, arduino

I am in the process of making a GPS tracker with a SIM7000E module and an Arduino Nano.

I have added the results from a couple of AT commands into a bunch of "char's" in an attempt to add these chars at the end of a URL.

However, that URL is not printing properly.

AT commands are:

AT+CGNSPWR=1        *turns on GPS

AT+CGNSINF          *displays NMEA data

I will show the code.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial SIM7000E(10, 11); //RX, TX
int rx=10; 
int tx=11;
const char header[]  = "AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"http://dweet.io/dweet/for/mything?";
const char trailer[] = "\"\r\n";
//char ch[];

void setup() {
// put your setup code here, to run once:

pinMode(tx,OUTPUT);
pinMode(rx,INPUT);

Serial.begin(9600);
delay(1000);

SIM7000E.begin(19200);
delay(1000);

Serial.println("Initialising");
delay(1000);

SIM7000E.println("AT+CGNSPWR=1\r\n");
while(SIM7000E.available()) {
//Serial.write(SIM7000E.read());
}
delay(1000);

SIM7000E.println("AT+CGNSINF\r\n");
while (SIM7000E.available()) {
char ch[2] = {SIM7000E.read()};
char ch1[2] = {SIM7000E.read()};
char ch2[2] = {SIM7000E.read()};
char ch3[2] = {SIM7000E.read()};
char ch4[2] = {SIM7000E.read()};
char ch5[2] = {SIM7000E.read()};
char ch6[2] = {SIM7000E.read()};
char ch7[2] = {SIM7000E.read()};
char ch8[2] = {SIM7000E.read()};
char ch9[2] = {SIM7000E.read()};
char ch10[2] = {SIM7000E.read()};
char ch11[2] = {SIM7000E.read()};
char ch12[2] = {SIM7000E.read()};
char ch13[2] = {SIM7000E.read()};
char ch14[2] = {SIM7000E.read()};
char ch15[2] = {SIM7000E.read()};
char ch16[2] = {SIM7000E.read()};
char ch17[2] = {SIM7000E.read()};
char ch18[2] = {SIM7000E.read()};
char ch19[2] = {SIM7000E.read()};
char ch20[2] = {SIM7000E.read()};
char ch21[2] = {SIM7000E.read()};
char ch22[2] = {SIM7000E.read()};
char ch23[2] = {SIM7000E.read()};
char ch24[2] = {SIM7000E.read()};
char ch25[2] = {SIM7000E.read()};
char ch26[2] = {SIM7000E.read()};
char ch27[2] = {SIM7000E.read()};
char ch28[2] = {SIM7000E.read()};
char ch29[2] = {SIM7000E.read()};
char ch30[2] = {SIM7000E.read()};
char ch31[2] = {SIM7000E.read()};
char ch32[2] = {SIM7000E.read()};
char ch33[2] = {SIM7000E.read()};
char ch34[2] = {SIM7000E.read()};
char ch35[2] = {SIM7000E.read()};
char ch36[2] = {SIM7000E.read()};
char ch37[2] = {SIM7000E.read()};
char ch38[2] = {SIM7000E.read()};
char ch39[2] = {SIM7000E.read()};
char ch40[2] = {SIM7000E.read()};
char ch41[2] = {SIM7000E.read()};
char ch42[2] = {SIM7000E.read()};
char ch43[2] = {SIM7000E.read()};
char ch44[2] = {SIM7000E.read()};
char ch45[2] = {SIM7000E.read()};
char ch46[2] = {SIM7000E.read()};

char url[150]= "";
strcat(url, header);
strcat(url, ch);
strcat(url, ch1);
strcat(url, ch2);
strcat(url, ch3);
strcat(url, ch4);
strcat(url, ch5);
strcat(url, ch6);
strcat(url, ch7);
strcat(url, ch8);
strcat(url, ch9);
strcat(url, ch10);
strcat(url, ch11);
strcat(url, ch12);
strcat(url, ch13);
strcat(url, ch14);
strcat(url, ch15);
strcat(url, ch16);
strcat(url, ch17);
strcat(url, ch18);
strcat(url, ch19);
strcat(url, ch20);
strcat(url, ch21);
strcat(url, ch22);
strcat(url, ch23);
strcat(url, ch24);
strcat(url, trailer);
Serial.println(url);
// puts (url);
return 0;

}

delay(1000);

SIM7000E.print("AT\r\n");
while(SIM7000E.available())
Serial.write(SIM7000E.read());
delay(2000);

}

void loop() {
// put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

The results are:

> AT+HTTPPARA="URL","http://dweet.io/dweet/for/mything?AT+CGNSPWR=1
> OK
> ⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮"

Ideally, it should be :

> AT+HTTPPARA="URL","http://dweet.io/dweet/for/mything?AT+CGNSPWR=1 OK AT+CGNSINF +CGNSINF: 1,1,20220702123007.000,-$7.521564,1%3.05"

I know I'll have to get rid of the spaces. But one step at a time...

As you can see, it adds the first command and the result from the first command onto the end of the URL. But it does not add the second command (the most important command) or its results onto the end of the URL.

I do not know why.

The endgame is to use this URL to send to dweet . io

If anyone could give me some direction as to how or why this is happening, I'd appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is because you're not null terminating your sting with '\0'

```
char url[150];
memset(url, 0, 150)
```

**BUT**

before we start you need to learn about arrays and for loops.
you could join this all together without the strcat by simply

```
const int maxCharacters = 47;

//note maxCharacters + 1 because you NEED to null terminate your strings, this is your error.
char ch[maxCharacters + 1 ];
memset(ch, 0, maxCharacters + 1);

while (SIM7000E.available()) {
   for(int i =0; i < maxCharacters; i++){
      ch[i] =  SIM7000E.read();
   }
   Serial.println(ch);
}
```

Other obvious issues

- Does SIM7000E.read() always return characters? I changed the code as you allocate an array of 2 for it, but I'm fairly sure this will return a single char.
- Does SIM7000E.read() block until it receives a character?
- Will you always get 47 characters? Or should it read a time character if SIM7000E.available()?

Something more like:

```
int index = 0;
while (SIM7000E.available() && index < maxCharacters ) {
    ch[index++] =  SIM7000E.read();
}
Serial.println(ch);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I allocated an array of 2 for each char as I wanted one letter/number/symbol to be printed at a time. I dont think I have coded SIM7000E.read() to block until it receives characters. The number of characters may change slightly each time. Ill try and incorporate some of your code into mine

Comment: Hopefully it helps. You could do this through Serial.println(&ch[index - 1]);  assuming println takes a char* and is looking for the null termination